# Payment Method Tab customize OpenCart

Tags: php, methods, opencart, extension-methods, payment

Is there any solution to customize payment method tab in opencart.
Basically what i needed is on selecting a payment method, options related to that particular method bind below that selected payment method.
I want it to be separated ,like i don't want to customize the core files.

Answer (score 0):

Opencart uses php MVC framework, the payment method controller files are in catalog/controller/extension/payment folder and view files are inside the catalog/view/theme/default/template/extension/payment folders.
You can customize these two files for desired behavior. If you don't want to edit core files, you may need to require OCMOD knowledge, that is an xml file created according to customization and then imported through extension installer.
You can learn about ocmod system https://github.com/opencart/opencart/wiki/Modification-System

Comment: Hello Saqib , Its mentioned in doc OCMOD will be removed from opencart source code , only the event system will be used for modifications, 
Can you please share any link for event / hooks to modify payment method tab.